# Jackson custom deserializer of multiple properties into value object class

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Let's say I have following flat JSON structure:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "validFrom": "2018-01-09",
    "validTo": "2018-01-10",
}
```

and `MyPojo` class:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String name;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Validity validity;
}
```

and `Validity` class:

```
public class Validity {
    private LocalDate validFrom;
    private LocalDate validTo;
}
```

I created custom unwrapping serializer and it works fine.

I would like to deserialize JSON above into `MyPojo` class which includes `Validity` value object.

How should custom deserializer for `Validity` be implemented?

`@JsonProperty` does not work as I want to use 2 Json properties for `Validity` construction

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a constructor in this case, a lot simpler than a custom deserializer, something like:

```
@JsonCreator
public MyPojo(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
              @JsonProperty("validFrom") String validFrom,
              @JsonProperty("validTo") String validTo) {
    this.name = name;
    this.validity = new Validity(validFrom, validTo);
}
```

It's implied that [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is parsed from [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) above but you may have Jackson parse them.

You may skip annotations above if you use Java 8 with [parameter names module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names)

That will require an extra annotation on validity, see open Jackson issue [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1497)

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
@JsonUnwrapped
private Validity validity;
```

Comment: What if I want constructor MyPojo(String name, Validity validity)? Is it possible?

Comment: That throws : `InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot define Creator property "validity" as @JsonUnwrapped: combination not yet supported`